# WSDL Connection Issue in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect to a WSDL file and keep getting this error:

`Bad auth String (could not parse username/password): String index out of range: -1`

I am able to connect to a local WSDL file without any errors, but now I am trying to connect a file on an external server. I was provided with a username and password, but am unsure of how to pass these arguments in.

Here is where I am entering in my login credentials:

```
     MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
     SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();       
     String loginPassword = "myusername:mypassword";
     soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + loginPassword);
```

On another note, I am printing statements after my Soap Request, which appears to be working and after my Soap Response. The `Bad auth String (could not parse username/password): String index out of range: -1`  I know that are more secure ways of entering a username and password, but at this point I am just trying to make a successful call.

Comment: it could be this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29916/why-does-http-basic-authentication-encode-the-username-and-password-with-base64

Comment: What @McKevin said.  You need to convert your loginPassword to bytes with `getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` and then [base 64 encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-) those bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username password for Basic authentication is Base 64 encoded. Hope this will help.

I have a sample for Basic authentication for Inputstream:-

```
public static InputStream getInputStream(String location) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(location);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String userpass = username + ":" + password;
        String basicAuth = "Basic "
                + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass
                        .getBytes());
        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        return uc.getInputStream();
}
```

Another very unsecure way of doing it is by http://user:password@www.example.com. Only use this on developer environment.